# Multiple Windows recovery image deployment via Linux PXE server?

Tags: linux, windows, pxe, deployment

Is the following scenario feasible:

A laptop repair workshop currently using multiple, physical hard disk caddies containing various Windows 7 / 8 recovery images for repairing various laptop models wishes to replace the physical caddy system with a single Linux server.

The server would host these different recovery images and allow multiple technicians to simultaneously access whichever recovery image they need to recover laptops with faulty Windows installations.

My research so far into Linux server options with DHCP, TFTP, PXE capability and tools such as CloneZilla, FOG, CrucibleWDS, seem to describe a scenario in which a single Windows image is being deployed to multiple machines within a company, as opposed to providing access to multiple windows recovery images for multiple laptop models that are simultaneously accessible by technicians via a PXE network boot.

Can this be done?

Many thanks in advance for words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with CloneZilla as I have tried it before.

Single image to Multiple machine simultaneously (Multicast) is one of the most wanted feature. That's why you found many posts talking about it.

As you can see its feature on the official site: [clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org/).

> - The image file can be on local disk, ssh server, samba server, NFS server or WebDAV server.

CloneZilla will bring to you a menu after loading to choose what you want to do: make backup, restore...

It let choose which image and from where to get, even you enter custom one (from any server in the network with supported protocol). It does not have to be predefined within CloneZilla settings.

[image: CloneZilla Image Repository]